# android.location.Address not recognized by AIDL?

Tags: android, service, gps, location, aidl

I'm trying to pass back a `List<Address>` object from a remote service and I can't seem to figure out why this is happening, but when I try to `import android.location.Address` into my Android `AIDL` file, my IDE (Eclipse) hi-lights the import as an error.  It's strange because Address implements the Parcelable interface (and so does android.location.Location, which does not get hi-lighted as an error) so I would expect no issues in doing this. Any ideas what's going on?

The Android platform I'm working on is 4.2.2 Jelly Bean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although `android.location.Address` implements the `Parcelable` interface, it does not seem to be declared as `parcelable` in `sdk/platforms/android-<api-level>/framework.aidl`. As a workaround you can either to add the line:

```
parcelable android.location.Address;
```

to the `framework.aidl` file for corresponding API level (17 in the case of 4.2.2 JellyBean).

Another approach, which I prefer over modifying the `framework.aidl` file directly, is to add an AIDL interface file containing the `parcelable` declaration to your project at `src/android/location/Address.aidl` containing:

```
package android.location;
parcelable Address;
```

Why `android.location.Address` is not declared as `parcelable` in the `framework.aidl` in the first place I do not know.